# Como salvar checkbox no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Minha dúvida é bem simples, porém não achei exatamente o comando que quero e espero que me consigam ajudar.

Tenho uma página de orçamento de veículos e quero fazer um `checkbox` para selecionar entre três modelos de rodas e quero que este salve no banco de dados na tabela `orçamento` como `idroda`.

Tenho o banco já criado, e a tabela onde quero salvar a `id` do `checkbox` escolhida  seria `orcamento`.

Então o meu objetivo seria primeiramente de salvar o `checkbox` no banco de dados.

Segue o meu código.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="checkbox"/>
<div id="ola">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ba[]" value="opção 1"/>opção 1<br />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ba[]" value="opção 2"/>opção 2<br />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ba[]" value="opção 3"/>opção 3<br />
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" value="enviar" name="acao"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["ba"])) 
{ 
    echo "você escolheu:<br>"; 
}


if (isset ($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == "enviar"){

    if(!empty($_POST['ba'])){
        $campo = $_POST['ba'];
        foreach($campo as $valor){
            echo $valor.'<br/>';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Nada marcado";
    }
}
```

Comment: Você já possui um banco criado? É acostumado a trabalhar com SQL? Caso possua o banco explique qual a tabela que quer inserir a informação.

Comment: Você quer que salve os 3 ids em um único registro ou cada id em um registro diferente? Se tiver a estrutura do banco, coloque na pergunta

Comment: No lugar do `echo` faça o insert na tabela de orcamentos.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Bruno! Por favor invista um minuto do seu tempo fazendo o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), para conhecer melhor como o site funciona. Eu sugiro também que você responda aos pedidos de informações dos outros usuários se quiser uma boa resposta à sua pergunta (eles não recebem para te ajudar!).